# How to temporarily mount a broken off mirror leg from a LVM partition

Tags: lvm, mount, mirror, disk-volume

I mirrored my filesystem onto 3 drives using LVM mirror.

I broke off one of it's legs, by simply unplugging an external drive, before upgrading Ubuntu to 19.10.

So I started the upgrade, but having that drive removed made the system unbootable! I had my grub on that external drive. After fixing the boot problem I finally got the system back, but the upgrade did not go smoothly. In order to fix MariaDB I now would like to gain access to my old `my.cnf` file located on that external hard drive

How would I temporarily mount that LVM mirror leg to gain access to that file?

```
sudo -i
lvmdiskscan
  /dev/loop0  [    <104.13 MiB] 
  /dev/loop1  [    <153.47 MiB] 
  /dev/sda1   [    <930.73 GiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/loop3  [      42.80 MiB] 
  ...
  /dev/sdb1   [    <465.76 GiB] LVM physical volume
  ...
  /dev/sdc1   [    <222.23 GiB] LVM physical volume
  ...
  /dev/loop38 [      51.30 MiB] 
  0 disks
  36 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  3 LVM physical volumes
```

`/dev/sdc1` is my external hard drive. So in order to mount it I did

```
mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt
```

but I am getting this error:

> mount: /mnt: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'.

How would I go about mounting it?

```
pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree   
  /dev/sda1  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <930.73g  704.08g
  /dev/sdb1  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <465.76g  239.12g
  /dev/sdc1            lvm2 ---  <222.23g <222.23g
```

```
lvdisplay /dev/sdc1
  Volume group "sdc1" not found
  Cannot process volume group sdc1
```

the drive to mount:

[image: drive to mount]

Answer (score 0):

The logical volume on that system is `/dev/ubuntu-vg/root`. Paging space at  `/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap` would not have a file system.

There is no volume on `/dev/sdc1`. It has LVM2 metadata, but pvs does not show it in a VG, and it is 100% empty.

How exactly this happened depends on the commands used to create the mirror, and your recovery steps. It is possible to have a mirror log on a separate PV from the data. (Note that raid1 is different from mirror, see man `lvmraid`.) Or creating the mirror volume never used `sdc1` as you assumed.

Recover or rebuild that file some other way.

---

A better way to take a backup is snapshots.

Create an LVM snapshot volume. Copy off it it to the external storage. Either mount the snapshot as a file system and copy files, or copy the snapshot as an image with `dd`.

Comment: I remember seeing it "work" during the building of the mirror. It took some time. What was it doing if not mirroring the data?

Comment: Cannot tell without more details on how you created the mirror and how you recovered it. Possible that your recovery reduced sdc1 out of the volume group.

Comment: At a given point I renamed the VG of the two internal drives, in the hope of not causing some conflict with the external drive. I did this having the external drive unplugged. Somehow the renaming caused the external drive to dump that original VG name all together.

Comment: If what you say is true, I do not see how this happened. Start data recovery on a copy of the PV, bring in a professional if you do not know how. In parallel, evaluate how to rebuild any valuable files from nothing.

Comment: I gave up on the idea of ever recovering that `my.cnf` file. It was easy to just replace it. But thank you for all the help.